# java play framework order and limit by child field to json

Tags: java, sql, json, jpa, playframework

I have a Campaign class, a Hotel Class and an Image class.

A Hotel has many Images and Campaigns, but a Campaign and Image can only have one Hotel.

I want (with Play! Framework 2.x) to select the top 5 Campaigns and their respective Hotel and it's Images and put it into a nice JSON like `Json.toJson()` method does.

How can I accomplish this? I've been searching for hours, looked at FetchType LAZY and EAGER and tried all kinds of stuff but i found nothing to work. Last thing I want to do is to manually loop and build the JSON.

To generate a nice JSON sorted by the Hotels all I do is call from my Hotel model `Json.toJson(Hotel.all());` and it will generate a JSON with all campaigns and images.

But what I want is to generate only 5 campaigns and I want to list only 5 campaigns and their hotel and its images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get a list of 5 hotels:
`List<Hotel> hotelList = new Model.Finder(String.class, Hotel.class).setMaxRows(5).findList();`

Comment: Hello jlars62! This is exactly what i've been doing now but what this does is that it orders by the hotel's id and lists all campaigns of that hotel.

What i want to do is list 5 campaignn(ordered by the campaigns id) and its respective hotel and its images.

Comment: You see at the moment my JSON kind of looks like this http://pastebin.com/PVQpWSLg

And i want it to look like this http://pastebin.com/jmUer6Tm

You see the id's/order switched places?

Basically i need to loop through through all the campaigns manually and then find their hotel and images and construct the JSON myself. But it'd be nice with a way to do it quickly  as with everything else.

Comment: Well, I am not an sql expert, so there may be a more efficient way to do this. But this should work for what you are trying to do. Use this code to get the hotels from the campaigns: `List<Hotel> hotelList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Campaign> campaignList = new Model.Finder(String.class, Campaign.class).setMaxRows(5).findList();
        for(Campaign c :campaignList) {
              hotelList.add(c.hotel);
        }` (continued)

Comment: @OscarLinde  In your Hotel class, have this line `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Campaign> campaign;` And this in your campaign class: `@ManyToOne
    public Hotel hotel;`

Comment: What those lines do is create a relationship between the Hotel and Campaign entities so that the Campaign entity knows what Hotel it is associated with. This is done by adding the Hotel primary key (id) to the Campaign table. Also, you may want to make those fields private and add getters and setters. I just used public so I could quickly test what I sent you.

Comment: Ah yes. But when i try to do Json.toJson(hotelList); i get an infinite recursion cycle. And i need to be able to fetch all campaigns from Restaurant class and vice versa, so i can't use @JsonIgnore on one of them. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Can you put `@JsonIgnore` on the getter for the `Hotel` field of your `Campaign` class?

Comment: @OscarLinde What is the relationship between your `Campaign` and `Restaurant` tables? Is it a many-to-many relationship?